# Fetch all the href links of a webpage using vba selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver

```
Option Explicit
Private chr As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub Test()
Set chr = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
chr.Start
chr.Get "https://www.grainger.com/category/pumps/rotary-pumps/rotary-gear-pump-heads? 
categoryIndex=1"
chr.Wait 1000

Dim mylinks As Selenium.WebElements
Dim mylink As Selenium.WebElement
Dim i As Long

Set mylinks = chr.FindElementsByTag("a")
For i = 0 To mylinks.Count
For Each mylink In mylinks
If LCase(mylink.Attribute("data-testid")) = "product-detail-title" Then
Debug.Print mylink.Attribute("href")
Exit For
End If
Next mylink
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

I was trying to extract all the href links present in that webpage link mentioned with the above code. But, the issue that i am facing is, whatever the first link it is fetching in the result, the same link is repeating  in the next loop also in the result till mylinks.count. I think, i'm missing something here, kindly suggest what needs to be corrected here to get all the links as i needed. Please advise.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why do you have 2 nested loops looping over `myLinks`? And why do you modify the counter of a `For`-loop?

Comment: The first href link it fetched was "grainger.com/product/DAYTON-Rotary-Gear-Pump-Head-Light-4KHK6", then it should have been fetched "grainger.com/product/DAYTON-Rotary-Gear-Pump-Head-Light-4KHK4", like wise it should continue until it fetches last href link in that page. But it is fetching only first link multiple times. That is why i tried to put two for loops over there in trying to resolve this problem.

Comment: Those 2 loops make absolute no sense. The inner loop is existed when the first matching link is found, starting the next iteration of the outer loop. This outer loop triggers again the same inner loop which of course find the same link again. Get rid of the outer loop and remove the `Exit For` that breaks the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the outer loop (which does not *seem to* make sense) and the  `Exit For` from the inner loop, and it should work henceforth.

```
Option Explicit
Private chr As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
    Set chr = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    chr.Start
    chr.Get "https://www.grainger.com/category/pumps/rotary-pumps/rotary-gear-pump-heads?categoryIndex=1"
    chr.Wait 1000

    Dim mylinks As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim mylink As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim i As Long

    Set mylinks = chr.FindElementsByTag("a")
    For Each mylink In mylinks
        If LCase(mylink.Attribute("data-testid")) = "product-detail-title" Then
            Debug.Print mylink.Attribute("href")
        End If
    Next mylink
End Sub
```